# Installing Ejabberd module does not start underlying dependencies

Tags: elixir, ejabberd

I am attempting to run a custom elixir plugin in Ejabberd to send an SQS message to a queue (using the ex_aws library) for certain Ejabberd hooks. However, when I install the plugin to Ejabberd using `mix module_install plugin_name` and trigger the ejabberd hook, the ex_aws dependencies don't seem to be started.

My mix.exs file:

```
defmodule PluginName.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [
      app: :plugin_name,
      version: "0.2.0",
      elixir: "~> 1.8",
      build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
      start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
      deps: deps(),
      test_coverage: [tool: ExCoveralls],
      preferred_cli_env: [
        "coveralls":        :test,
        "coveralls.detail": :test,
        "coveralls.post":   :test,
        "coveralls.html":   :test
      ],
      dialyzer: [
        flags: [:error_handling, :race_conditions]
      ]
    ]
  end

  def application do
    [extra_applications: [:logger, :amqp, :ex_aws, :ex_aws_sts, :ex_aws_sqs]]
  end

  defp deps do
    [
      {:sweet_xml, "~> 0.6"},
      {:configparser_ex, "~> 4.0"},
      {:saxy, "~> 1.1"},
      {:ex_aws, "~> 2.1"},
      {:ex_aws_sts, "~> 2.1"},
      {:ex_aws_sqs, "~> 3.2"},
      {:hackney, "~> 1.9"},
      {:credo, "~> 0.8",           only: [:dev, :test], runtime: false},
      {:dialyxir, "~> 1.0.0-rc.6", only: [:dev],        runtime: false},
      {:excoveralls, "~> 0.7", only: :test},
      {:mock, "~> 0.3.3",      only: :test},
      {:amqp, "~> 1.1.1"},
      {:poison, "~> 3.1"},
      {:reunion,  git: "https://github.com/snar/reunion",        branch: "master", runtime: false},
      {:ejabberd, git: "redacted", branch: "master", runtime: false},
      {:xmpp, "~> 1.3.0"}
    ]
  end
end
```

The error message I am seeing:

```
2021-03-01 22:40:30.105 [error] <0.1206.0>@Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache:get:20 gen_server sqs_client terminated with reason: bad argument in call to ets:lookup('Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache', aws_instance_auth) in 'Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache':get/1 line 20
2021-03-01 22:40:30.105 [error] <0.1206.0>@Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache:get:20 CRASH REPORT Process sqs_client with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: bad argument in call to ets:lookup('Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache', aws_instance_auth) in 'Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache':get/1 line 20
2021-03-01 22:40:30.108 [error] <0.2520.0>@ejabberd_hooks:safe_apply:384 Hook offline_message_hook crashed when running 'Elixir.PluginName':on_offline_msg/1:
** Reason = {exit,{{badarg,[{ets,lookup,['Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache',aws_instance_auth],[]},{'Elixir.ExAws.Config.AuthCache',get,1,[{file,"lib/ex_aws/config/auth_cache.ex"},{line,20}]},{'Elixir.ExAws.Config',retrieve_runtime_value,2,[{file,"lib/ex_aws/config.ex"},{line,84}]},{'Elixir.Stream','-map/2-fun-0-',4,[{file,"lib/stream.ex"},{line,495}]},{'Elixir.Enumerable.List',reduce,3,[{file,"lib/enum.ex"},{line,3080}]},{'Elixir.Enumerable.Stream',do_each,4,[{file,"lib/stream.ex"},{line,1405}]},{'Elixir.Enum',find,3,[{file,"lib/enum.ex"},{line,868}]},{'Elixir.ExAws.Config','-retrieve_runtime_config/1-fun-0-',2,[{file,"lib/ex_aws/config.ex"},{line,71}]}]},{'Elixir.GenServer',call,[sqs_client,{publish_sqs,<<redacted>>},5000]}},[{'Elixir.GenServer',call,3,[{file,"lib/gen_server.ex"},{line,737}]},{'Elixir.PluginName',on_offline_msg,1,[{file,"lib/plugin_name.ex"},{line,161}]},{ejabberd_hooks,safe_apply,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,381}]},{ejabberd_hooks,run_fold1,4,[{file,"src/ejabberd_hooks.erl"},{line,365}]},{maps,fold_1,3,[{file,"maps.erl"},{line,232}]},{mod_muc_room,process_groupchat_message,2,[{file,"src/mod_muc_room.erl"},{line,798}]},{p1_fsm,handle_msg,10,[{file,"src/p1_fsm.erl"},{line,582}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,249}]}]}
```

I have tried using `Application.ensure_all_started(:ex_aws)` in the plugin's start() method but that does not fix the issue.

Comment: Show us whole `mix.exs`.

Comment: @Hauleth edited my post for the whole mix.exs file